# Refresh Facebook access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the [Facebook Login for Devices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/for-devices#tech) API to authenticate a device that only has a display where I want to display `Page` information.

I am able to authenticate fine and get an access token and display page information like I want but how do I refresh the access token that was given to me when the user put in the device code to allow the device by going to `facebook.com/devices`? I cant have the user do this every 60 days or whenever the token expires.

I have not found any documentation about how to refresh them other than saying that the native sdk's do it automatically. Can anyone point me to documentation or something where I can refresh access tokens?

Comment: If you  are using the Native SDK it does it automatically. Otherwise there is no way to do it.

Comment: @WizKid so the user would then have to go and re-authorize the device again after every 60 days? That cant be real, what a horrible user experience that is

Comment: The user is probably happier to do that compared to the app will forever be able to do things as them even if they don't use the app anymore

Comment: @WizKid the user in the case is not the general public, there are many valid use cases for this so to say that all users would be happier is a bad statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the Facebook Sdk for Android I found that its a simple graph api call that you can make to extend an access token

```
private static GraphRequest createExtendAccessTokenRequest(AccessToken accessToken, GraphRequest.Callback callback) {
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("grant_type", "fb_extend_sso_token");
    parameters.putString("client_id", accessToken.getApplicationId());
    return new GraphRequest(
        accessToken, TOKEN_EXTEND_GRAPH_PATH, parameters, HttpMethod.GET, callback);
  }
```

Where `TOKEN_EXTEND_GRAPH_PATH` is `oauth/access_token`